# Converting integers to _LARGE_INTEGERS

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to call `NtDelayExecution` but can't seem to figure out how to convert an `int` to a `_LARGE_INTEGER` (the format that the `NtDelayExecution` function requests).
(http://www.codewarrior.cn/ntdoc/winnt/ex/NtDelayExecution.htm)

My current code is:

```
    LARGE_INTEGER DelayTimeConverted = HIBERNATION_TIME;
    ((NtDelayExecPrototype)(NtDelayExecutionPtr))(FALSE, DelayTimeConverted);
```

Where `HIBERNATION_TIME` is defined as:
`#define HIBERATNATION_TIME 123` (placeholder value).

When I try to compile, I get an error along the lines of `no suitable constructor exists to convert int to _LARGE_INTEGER` - any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My platform is Windows 10 and I've tried changing my typedef for the function where `_LARGE_INTEGER` is now `unsigned int` but the delay doesn't occur.

EDIT2: Here is my full function:

```
void NtDelayExecution (  ) {
    typedef void(WINAPI* NtDelayExecPrototype)(BOOLEAN, PLARGE_INTEGER);//PLARGE_INTEGER);

    FARPROC NtDelayExecutionPtr = 0x0;
    HMODULE NtDLLModule = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll");
    // Error checking omitted.

    LARGE_INTEGER DelayTimeConverted;
    DelayTimeConverted.QuadPart = HIBERNATION_TIME;
    ((NtDelayExecPrototype)(NtDelayExecutionPtr))(FALSE, &DelayTimeConverted);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1) has instructions on how to use it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1) `LARGEINTEGER` is a `union`, and you'll need to pick a member to initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LARGE_INTEGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1) is a `union` containing two 32-bit integers `LowPart` (`DWORD`) and `HighPart` (`LONG`) laying on top of a 64-bit integer `QuadPart` (`LONGLONG`):

```c
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  } u;
  LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

In this case, you can assign your `int` to the `QuadPart` member:

```c
LARGE_INTEGER DelayTimeConverted;
DelayTimeConverted.QuadPart = HIBERNATION_TIME;
((NtDelayExecPrototype)(NtDelayExecutionPtr))(FALSE, &DelayTimeConverted);
```

Also note the `&`, since `NtDelayExecution()` takes the `LARGE_INTEGER` by pointer (that is what the `P` in `PLARGE_INTEGER` stands for).

---

**UPDATE**: That being said, the function you have shown is calling `GetModuleHandle()`, but where is it calling `GetProcAddress()` afterwards to initialize `NtDelayExecutionPtr`? You should be doing something like this:

```c
NTSTATUS NtDelayExecution()
{
    typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI* NtDelayExecPrototype)(BOOLEAN, PLARGE_INTEGER);

    HMODULE NtDLLModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll"));
    NtDelayExecPrototype NtDelayExecutionPtr = GetProcAddress(NtDLLModule, "NtDelayExecution");

    if (NtDelayExecutionPtr == NULL)
        return STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;

    LARGE_INTEGER DelayTimeConverted;
    DelayTimeConverted.QuadPart = HIBERNATION_TIME;
    return NtDelayExecutionPtr(FALSE, &DelayTimeConverted);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still isn't working (No delay after calling NtDelayExecution).